# how to find current financial year if balance date is 1-march-2023

Tags: python-3.x

if date id 1-march-2023 then it should print

```
1-march-2022 to 31-april-2022
1-may-2022 to 30-june-2022
1-june-2022 to 31-july-2022
1-aug-2022 to 31-sept-2022
1-oct-2022 to 30-nov-2022
1-dec-2022 to 31-jan-2023
```

i am trying to find current financial year in this format if balance date will be 1-march-2023 then find 1 year complete date in 2 month sequence.
i am trying this code but not working

```
def generate_two_month_sequences(start_date):
    sequences = []
    for _ in range(6):
        end_date = (start_date + timedelta(days=59)).replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
        sequences.append((start_date, end_date))
        start_date = end_date + timedelta(days=1)
    return sequences
balance_date = datetime(2023, 6, 1)
financial_start_date = (balance_date.replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)).replace(day=1)
financial_start_date -= timedelta(days=365)  # Adjust to the previous year
two_month_sequences = generate_two_month_sequences(financial_start_date)

for start_date, end_date in two_month_sequences:
    print(f"{start_date.strftime('%d %B %Y')} to {end_date.strftime('%d %B %Y')}")
```